# How to convert .shp to lat and long coordinates en excel?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, coordinates, excel

I am trying to convert the below SHP file into lat and long coordinates in excel. I have no idea how to code or even find where the coding section is.

[image: map image]

Comment: Weclome to GIS.SE! If you don't need work in excel I am sure that there is some export/transformation function in ArcMap (I am not ArcMap user)

Comment: What format do you need the coordinates in?  Is it for one feature or many?  And most importantly, what have you tried?

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking to find out the vertex geometries, you can do the following:

1. [Feature vertices to points](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/feature-vertices-to-points.htm)
2. Add two fields within the new shapefile - lat and long - type: float
3. [Calculate geometry](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/tables/calculating-area-length-and-other-geometric-properties.htm) of lat/long fields

If you want to use python you can do the following:

```
import arcpy
ws = arcpy.env.workspace = r"path/to/workspace"
fc = r"path/to/shapefile"
feat_to_points = arcpy.FeatureVerticesToPoints_management (fc, "feat_to_points", "ALL")

arcpy.AddField_management (feat_to_points, "Lat", "FLOAT")
arcpy.AddField_management (feat_to_points, "Long", "FLOAT")

wgs = arcpy.SpatialReference(4326)
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(feat_to_points, ['SHAPE@', 'Lat', 'Long']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        pnt_wgs = row[0].projectAs(wgs)
        row[1:] = [pnt_wgs.centroid.Y, pnt_wgs.centroid.X] 
        rows.updateRow(row)
```

The resultant shapefile will create a DBF  file, which can be viewed in Excel.

Comment: QGIS DESKTOP OR OGR2OGR can do that simple conversion. First you want.to make sure the Shape file is in 4326 geographic wgs84